# How does a zero register improve performance?

Tags: mips, cpu-registers, instruction-set

In the MIPS ISA, there's a zero register (`$r0`) which always gives a value of zero. This allows the processor to:

1. Any instruction which produces result that is to be discarded can direct its target to this register
2. To be a source of `0`

It is said in this [source](https://web.archive.org/web/20170328171837/http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Overall/instruction.html) that this improved the speed of the CPU. How does it improve performance? And what are the reasons why not all ISA adopt this zero register?

> **$r0** is not general purpose. It is hardwired to 0. No matter what you
> do to this register, it always has a value of 0. You might wonder why
> such a register is needed in MIPS.
>
> The designers of MIPS used benchmarks (programs used to determine the
> performance of a CPU), which convinced them that having a register
> hardwired to 0 would improve the performance (speed) of the CPU as
> opposed to not having it. Not everyone agrees a register hardwired to
> 0 is essential, so not all ISAs have a zero register.

Comment: Perhaps the zero register makes the CPU faster in the sense that it allows many programs to be written in less instructions.

Comment: Related question on ElectricalEngineering.SE: [Why MIPS uses R0 as “zero” when you could just XOR two registers to produce 0?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/293830/56807)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's a few potential ways that this can improve performance; it's not clear which ones apply to that particular processor, but I've listed them roughly in order from most to least likely.

1. It avoids spurious pipeline stalls. Without an explicit zero register, it's necessary to take a register, zero it out, and use its value. This means that the zero-using operation is dependent on the zeroing operation, and (depending on how powerful the pipeline forwarding system is) possibly on the zeroed register's previous value. Architectures like x86, which have quite small register files and basically virtualize their registers to keep that from causing problems, have extremely powerful hazard analysis tools. The same is not generally true of RISC processors.
2. Certain operations may be more pipelineable if they can avoid a register read. If an explicit zero register is used, the fact that the operand will be zero is known at the instruction decode stage, rather than later on in the register fetch stage. Thus, the register read stage can be skipped.
3. Similarly, the ability to explicitly discard results avoids the need for a register write stage.
4. Certain operations may generate simpler microcode when one of their operands is known to be zero, or when the result is known to be discarded.
5. An explicit zero register takes some pressure off the compiler's optimizer, as it doesn't need to be as careful with its register assignment (no need to identify a register which won't cause a stall on read or write).

Comment: On simpler CPUs, there are benefits to decoding if the ISA needs fewer opcodes.  Having a zero register means mov-immediate to register can be an alias for `ori dst, $zero, 1234` instead of needing its own opcode.  On an ISA with FLAGS (unlike MIPS), `cmp` can be `sub` with `$zero` as a destination.

Answer (score 6):

For each of your items, here's an answer.

1. Consider instructions that compulsory take a register for output, where you want to discard this output. Normally, you'd have to make sure that you have a free register available, and if not, push some of your current registers onto the stack, which is a costly operation. Evidently, it happens a lot that the output of operations is discarded, and the easiest way to deal with this is to have a 'unused' register available.
2. Now that we have such an unused register, why not use it? It happens a lot that you want to zero-initialize something or compare something to zero. The long way is to first write zero to that register (which requires an extra instruction **and** the literal for zero in your machine code, which may be of the form `0x00000000` which is rather long) and then use it. So, one instruction shaved off and a little bit of your program size as well.

These optimizations may seem a bit trivial and may raise the question 'how much does that actually improve anything?' The answer here is that the operations described above are apparently used a lot on your MIPS processor.

Comment: Discarding the output of an instruction is useful on the x86 where instructions have side effects like setting condition codes. MIPS instructions only have one output, since this is a RISC architecture, and it is rarely necessary to discard an instruction's output.

Answer (score 3):

The concept of a zero register is not new.   I first encountered it on a CDC 6600 mainframe, which dates back to the mid-to-late 1960's.  In some ways it was one of the first RISC processors, and was the world's fastest computer for 5 years.   In that architecture, the "B0" register was hardwired to always be zero.   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDC_6600

The benefit of such a register is primarily that it simplified the instruction set.   When the decoding and orchestration of simple and regular instruction sets can be implemented *without microcode*, it increases performance.   In addition, for the 6600 like most LSI chips today, the time spent for a signal to travel the length a "wire" becomes on of the key factors in execution speed, and keeping the instruction set simple (and avoiding microcode) allows less transistors, and results in shorter circuit paths.

Answer (score 1):

A zero register allows saving some opcodes when designing a new
instruction set architecture (ISA).

For example, the [main RISC-V spec](https://content.riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/riscv-spec.pdf) has 32 pseudo-instructions that 
depend on the zero register (cf. Tables 26.2 and 26.3). A pseudo-instruction is an
instruction that is mapped by the assembler to another real
instruction (for example, branch-if-equal-to-zero is mapped to
branch-if-equal). For comparison: the main RISV-V spec lists 164
real instruction opcodes (i.e. counting RV(32|64)[IMAFD] base/extensions, a.k.a. RV64G). That means without a zero register RISC-V RV64G would occupy 32 more opcodes for those instructions (i.e. 20 % more). For a concrete RISC-V CPU
implementation, this real-to-pseudo instruction ratio may shift in either direction
depending on which extensions are selected.

Having less opcodes simplifies the instruction decoder.

A more complex decoder needs more time for decoding instructions
or occupies more gates (that can't be used for more useful CPU units)
or both.

Existing, incrementally developed ISAs have to deal with
backwards-compatibility. Thus, if your original ISA design
doesn't include a zero register, you can't just add it in a later
revision without breaking compatibility. Also, if your existing
ISA already requires a very complex decoder, adding then a zero
register doesn't pay off.

Besides the modern RISC-V ISA (developed since 2010, first 
ratification in 2019), ARMv8 AArch64 (a 64 Bit ISA released in 2011),
in contrast to the previous ARM 32 bit ISAs, also features a zero register. Because of this and other changes
AArch64 ISA has much less in common with previous ARM 32 Bit
ISAs than - say - x86 and x86-64 ISAs.

In contrast to AArch64, x86-64
doesn't has a zero register. Although x86-64 is more modern than
the previous 32 bit x86 ISA, its ISA only changed incrementally.
Thus, it features all the existing x86 opcodes plus 64 bit
variants, and thus the decoder already is very complex.