# What does GCC MIPS backend do with zero register?

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction

I noticed that MIPS has a zero register (built into hardware, wired to zero). MIPS ABI refers to the zero register by r0.

I am adding a new test backend to GCC and would like to have two such registers - one hardwired to zero, and another hardwired to 1. Now to add another register hard-wired to 1, I would like to reason about the compiler's handling of the zero register.

My question is how does GCC "use" the zero register - Of all the steps in the compilation workflow, in what all passes of GCC use this knowledge ?

Is it only the RTL generation pass (mapping zero consts to zero_register) or is there more to it ? My understanding is that it should be more than that (after reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24646101/how-does-a-zero-register-improve-performance) the purpose of having a zero register)

Comment: BEQ and BNE can use this register for comparisons with 0. Also, changing the sign (as in `-a`) can be done by subtracting from this register.